# R How did Rstudio know which project to open?

Tags: rstudio

I just curious on this question.
When you start a new project, and save some files, then close the Rstudio.
Next time you open Rstudio, it knows which project you are working on and will reopen it.
How come Rstudio knows it?
The guess is to check each project's .Rproj or .Rproj.user and pick the latest updated one.

But that is my guess, does anyone knows it?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is stored in the rstudio session cache in the file `sessions/active/<sessionid>/properites/project`. This is for RStudio server, but I assume that the desktop version uses the same mechanism.

Comment: this one? C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\RStudio\sessions\active it is empty, I am in windows 10

Comment: I see, maybe it is not in `active` but one of the other folders in sessions?

Comment: Seems there is no other folder under session, can you give me the full link in linux? That could give me some clue; sth like user/etc/sessions/active////?

Comment: The full link on linux for RStudio server  by default it is `~/.config/rstudio/`